# Can I prevent the user from adding more than two levels deep of terms inside of a taxonomy metabox?

Tags: php, custom-taxonomy, functions, metabox, terms

I'm in the process of creating a leveled tutorial structure in WordPress and want to build it so that it sets up the front-end with no code needed from the user.

So far, I have a custom post type called 'tut_page' that has a metabox for custom taxonomy called, 'tut_group' and terms can be added via the taxonomy metabox. For my register_taxonomy, the value for 'hierarchical' has been set to true. So I want levels, however I don't want more than two deep. I know that I can choose how many levels of terms to display in a template, but is there a way where I can just prevent users from creating terms that are deeper than two levels from the taxonomy metabox?

Here's what I have in functions.php for registering the taxonomy:

```
function create_tutorial_topic() {
    register_taxonomy(
        'tut_group', //name of taxonomy
        'tut_post', //object type e.g. our post type
        array(
                'labels' => array(
                'name' => _x( 'Tutorial Group', 'taxonomy general name' ),
                'singular_name' => _x( 'Tutorial Groups', 'taxonomy singular name' ),
                'search_items' =>  __( 'Search Tutorial Groups' ),
                'all_items' => __( 'All Tutorial Groups' ),
                'parent_item' => __( 'Parent Tutorial Groups' ),
                'parent_item_colon' => __( 'Parent Tutorial Groups:' ),
                'edit_item' => __( 'Edit Tutorial Group' ),
                'update_item' => __( 'Update Tutorial Group' ),
                'add_new_item' => __( 'Add Tutorial Group' ),
                'new_item_name' => __( 'New Tutorial Group' ),
                'menu_name' => __( 'Tutorial Group' ),
            ),
            'rewrite' => array( 'slug' => 'tutorial-group' ),
            'hierarchical' => true, //this is true but I only want two levels deep
        )
    );
}
```

I would also like to build as much this as much as I can myself without having to use a plugin. I tried searching on this site and found questions about limiting the number of terms, but not hierarchy levels. Thanks for any tips in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible, at least not safe.

The function `wp_insert_term( $term, $taxonomy, $args = array() )` that handles the creation of taxonomies provides a few filters and hooks, but the only one before the creation of the term in the database is

```
$term = apply_filters( 'pre_insert_term', $term, $taxonomy );
```

As you can see, the `$args` provided in the creation of the term are not passed to the filter - so you have no way of checking how many levels of the taxonomy exists by looking up `$args['parent']`.

An ugly way of doing it would be after the term is created, hooking into the action `created_term` or `create_term`, and checking it there. I have never done this myself, and you may open up a big can of worms deleting the term after creation with no possibility of returning an error afterwards.

If the filter `pre_insert_term` would accept the `$args` as an argument, it would me no problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I had a feeling this might not be possible, but I figured I'd ask in case. I was looking at the http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term and I noticed the parent=> in the $args array - all this does is assign whether or not the term is a parent, right? And as you were saying, doesn't differentiate between parent versus grandparent, for example?

Comment: All the $args['parent'] does is define if the term to be added has a parent, nothing else. It does not have anything to do with the function itself. No differentiation, sorry.